# Azure Notification Hub: 'Test Send' was successfully sent, but not any GCM traffic. Why?

Tags: azure, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

In the Azure Portal, I created a Notification Hub. And in "Push notification services - Google (GCM)", I entered the API Key value that I obtained from GCM.

In order to verify my settings of Azure Notification Hub and GCM, I ran 'Test Send' in Azure Portal - Notification Hub.

I got a message in Portal soon as below.

Successfully sent test message.  Outcome: {1 passed, 0 failed}.  Please see result section for details.

BUT I have not gotten any message traffic in GCM. 
Refer to the screenshot, please.
[image]

I have worked for a whole day but I'm still vague about what went wrong. 
Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a mobile (Android) client that is registered on both Notification Hubs and GCM?

NH won't send to GCM unless it has a registered client.

Comment: I was going through the tutorial of Microsoft: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-push/

I have finished the Android app and it works fine on virtual device in emulator except that it never received any notification from GCM.

Comment: I also wonder how to check if there are some devices which have been regsitered on GCM or Notification Hub.

Comment: The app works fine on AVD, and it has MyHandler class and code: ToDoActivity.mClient.getPush().register(gcmRegistrationId);. 

So I think it SHOULD have registered to GCM. 

But I don't know how to verify that. And my app also has not received notofications from GCM.

Comment: The easiest way is to fire up a Visual Studio instance, install the Azure SDK.  There is a place in the Server Explorer where you can see the devices that are registered, so you can see if the device is registered.  You can also send a test push from the same place and see if it was sent

Answer (score 0):

What @adrian-hall said and also see whether [Notification Hubs diagnosis guidelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer/) help.

There's also an article on [how to use Visual Studio Server Explorer to debug Notification Hubs issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530751.aspx#vs_explorer).

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to:

1. The package name in you manifest file, it **MUST** be the same to the package name when you create new App in the firebase
2. You need to change Google-Services.Json properties Build Action to googleServices.Json