# Visual studio 2015 Notification Hubs Diagnose 401 unauthorized

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-notificationhub

[image]
I got status 401 but two days ago worked fine.
Any idea ? How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you logged in in the Cloud Explorer? Can do expand the nodes there to see your Azure resources?

Comment: I am logged and I see my notification hub but I can't send a message like two day ago.

Comment: Could you go through the guides in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38905618/182371) and see if that helps?

Comment: ; / That answer don't help me.

Comment: I can't use notfication hubs from visal studio with localhost app, the same effect 401

Comment: Could you provide more details about your set up and what changed over the last couple of days? Also, did you try to restart VS/computer and re-login into the Cloud Explorer? Is there a chance you updated/re-created your hub which resulted in your connection string changing?

Comment: That is funny because nothing change, I tried reinstall VS but the same effect ; [

Comment: What's your namespace and hub name? Is it possible that you're on a different network compared to two days ago and some network calls do not get through now?

Comment: It could be different network because i switch between two network, but I tried on both and the same result. I created new notifi-hub but the same result...

Comment: From a different IP  everything works, so Microsoft block my others IP ?

Comment: I don't think it's Microsoft blocking your IP. It's possible that the other network doesn't get all the calls through, firewall settings or some other networking configuration difference.

Answer (score 0):

@wroe12 reported the problem has been solved. Turned out that when the solution worked originally and stopped working later, it occurred on two different networks. It's possible that the difference in those network configurations caused the problem.